# Meaning of tag of struts.xml file of a Java EE projects using struts 2 spring 3 and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2

I'm trying to make a project using struts 2, spring 3 and hibernate, but when I come to the step to write the struts.xml, I couldn't find a site which gave an explanation about the tag (and their attributes too) used in this file (tag such as package, action, result etc).

So is there any tutorial or refcard that gives an explanation about them?

What is the role that has in a Java EE project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are complete information about the various tags/attributes there layout in the xml DTD file. If you will use any IDE for the development it tend to give complete information about the elements and allowed attributes as well there positions.

Here are the links for some of documents for details

1. [The Struts 2 Document Type Definition (DTD)](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/strutsxml-examples.html).
2. [configuration-elements in struts.xml](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/configuration-elements.html)

Hope this will help you

Comment: You have invoked the IDE word, so i'm using the eclipse IDE, but do you know an eclipse plugin that support jee developement using Struts 2? A plugin that gives the features like autocompletion of struts.xml, wysiwyg editor for jsp pages using struts tags.

Comment: i am afraid its not there for Eclipse, but if you create a valid struts.xml file in the eclipse it can give you type ahead suggestion and its tend to validate your struts.xml file against the DTD and easily show error if you doing something wrong  in xml

Comment: @onepseudoxy MyEclipse has Struts 2 support, although I've never used it. Any XML editor, including those in an IDE, should have at least some support for XML editing and completion, although at varying levels.